# How to Direct Message a specific role in discord through discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py, bots

```
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
@client.command()
async def edm(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, Message):
    global members
    members = [m for m in ctx.guild.members if role in m.roles]
    for m in members:
        try:
            await m.send(Message)
            await ctx.send(f":white_check_mark: Message sent to {m}")
        except:
            await ctx.send(f":x: No DM could be sent to {m}")
    await ctx.send("Done!")
@edm.error
async def _edm_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BadArgument):
        await ctx.send(":x: Role couldn't be found!")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(f":x: {ctx.author.mention}, you don't have sufficient permissions.")
    else:
        await ctx.send(error)
```

This is my code and there are no errors as I am getting the resopnse from bot by sending a `Done!` from bot but still not sending direct messages to the role members.I wanted to dm a role like members role

Thanks For Help

Comment: Have you enabled Intents?

Comment: you shouldn't really do this and just mention the role in some channel. this is considered API abuse

Comment: Yes I have enable intents